# Best Error handling among error and catch in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, http-error

I am working on handling the http error response, I found 2 solutions for this. 1: using catch() method 2: using 'error', I am confused of which one is the best and less time consuming method.

My code is below:

**Method-1**

```
this.serviceName.methodName().catch(err => {
  // Handle error here
  console.log("Something went wrong with the request, please try again.");
  return Observable.throw(err.message.toUpperCase() || 'API_ERROR');
}).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

**Method-2:**

```
this.serviceName.methodName().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
},
error=>{
  console.log(error);
});
```

Please suggest which method is the good choice. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely not `catch`. The second one is good, you can also use the `catchError` operator and `throwError` too.

Comment: Have you seen [Getting error details](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details)

Comment: I have read it just now, I am new to angular. It says as `Error inspection, interpretation, and resolution is something you want to do in the service, not in the component.` So is it a bad idea to handle error in the component.ts file? or I can also handle error in it?

Comment: Also can you please explain how to do that in the service file as said in the angular.io